# Dummy code based on whether two other variable match each other

Tags: r, matching, dummy-variable

for my master thesis i am working with Rstudio and analyze M&A data. I want to create a dummy code (Firm relatedness yes/no) based on whether the acquiring & target firms SIC Code match.

I do know how to create dummy codes but not based on the matching of other two variables. can anyone help? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNpve.png)

below you find a link to the screenshot. so what i basically want to do or even know (if its possible) is to generate dummy values for the column Firm relatedness based on the match of NAICS Codes
e.g.: 221111 (acquirer naics code) & 221111 (target firm)
Firm relatedness 1, otherwise 0
i could do it manually in excel, but on a larger scale it would take some more time

Comment: Could you please share some data using `dput(df)`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Maybe `%in%` is what you are looking for?